# pandas df merge avoid duplicate column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

The question is when `merge` two `df`s, and they all have a column called `A`, then the result will be a df having `A_x` and `A_y`, I am wondering how to keep `A` from one `df` and discard another one, so that I don't have to rename `A_x` to `A` later on after the merge.

Comment: If `A` is `key` then there is no `A_x` and `A_y`. But if need only change columns suffixes use `print (df1.merge(df2, on='Key', suffixes=('','_')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter your dataframe columns before merging.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':np.arange(12),'A':np.random.randint(0,100,12),'C':list('ABCD')*3})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':np.arange(12),'A':np.random.randint(100,1000,12),'C':list('ABCD')*3})

df1.merge(df2[['Key','A']], on='Key')
```

Output:  (Note: C is not duplicated)

```
    A_x  C  Key  A_y
0    60  A    0  440
1    65  B    1  731
2    76  C    2  596
3    67  D    3  580
4    44  A    4  477
5    51  B    5  524
6     7  C    6  572
7    88  D    7  984
8    70  A    8  862
9    13  B    9  158
10   28  C   10  593
11   63  D   11  177
```

Comment: Same simply filter A from Df2 also,   Df2['Key'] inside the merge.

Comment: Or you can do something like what Jezrael is suggesting.  merge all, use null suffixes for the columns you want to keep and drop the rest.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if need append columns with duplicated columns names to final merged `DataFrame`:

...then add `suffixes` parameter to [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
print (df1.merge(df2, on='Key', suffixes=('', '_')))
```

--

... if not use [`@Scott Boston`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49733432/2901002) solution.